# About indecomposability and nilpotence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, nilpotent-matrices

Transferred from MSE where it now received a complete answer. 
Maybe the following is easy, but I am not an expert in finite-dimensional Lie algebras and was stuck on the following problem.

> Can you prove or disprove the following statement ?
>
> **S)** *Let $V$ be an indecomposable (finite-dimensional) module over a nilpotent $k$-Lie algebra ($k$ is algebraically closed), then there is a unique character $c: {\frak{g}}\to k$ ($c$ is linear and 
>   $[{\frak{g}},{\frak{g}}]\subset ker(c)$) such that, for all $g\in \frak{g}$, the operator 
>   $$
> \pi(g)-c(g)Id_V\in End_k(V)
> $$
>   is nilpotent ($\pi$ is the representation morphism).*

Comment: Math.SE link: [Indecomposable modules over nilpotent Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2684342).

Comment: [copied as answer to MathSE post] It's true and done in Bourbaki, *Groupes et algèbres de Lie* (*Lie groups and Lie algebras*), beginning of Chap VII. See esp. Prop 9 in §1.3 (on decomposition of modules over nilpotent Lie algebras).

Comment: Oh, thank you (+1 everywhere). This seems to solve my problem, I must enter the notations though (then, I will probably accept your answer on the basis of fruitful and spotted interaction :).

Comment: I've added a few details to the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is positive. Details and link to Bourbaki, Lie groups and Lie algebras, Chap VII, are given in [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2694748/35400).